# Install Windows Device Recovery tool stuck

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview, recovery-tool

I'm trying to install Windows Device Recovery tool, at first it was giving me the error "hash value not correct" (something like this), I searched and found out that I should install all updates and use the installer with compatibility mode as Windows 8...
Now it gets stuck on WinUSB Compatible ID Drivers, any ideas?

I'm a fast insider, but I need to go back to a stable version :/
This last build is unbearable...

Answer (score 1):

Since I own a Macbook, I had a lot of work to do this.. I'm writing it here in hope that someone who cares could read this and do something..

Initially I had to install a copy of Windows 10 on my Macbook, updated everything... but was not working because the windows was not activated..

Then I tried on another laptop with an Active Windows, but I had to install all the updates again, including Windows Defender and Office updates, which has nothing to do with the software I want to install. (Really stupid!)

After all this it should work, but in my case I had to remove the compatibility options on the installer, I had checked it during my tests, then it finally worked..

But the process of reverting my phone to a Stable Windows 10 was not finished yet, it took me one day, and I could not use my backup!

Answer (score 0):

Check out these FAQs regarding **Windows Device Recovery tool** on the microsoft website , the download link is also given , try this!
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987&tduid=(028b34ce9ce0a933d9d138c9de7937ce)(259740)(2542549)(d_wp)()

Comment: Can you summarise the solution in your own words? Link only answers can become useless if the link ever changes or becomes unavailable.

Comment: ...and that link comes up blank for me...

Comment: Yes, but they made such a mess with the installation trying to force things... Also that page page does not say the requirements for the installation to run smoothly.. (read my post)